# Add Extra Option Tag to Select Field - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using crispy forms to build my form. Now i want to add one more extra `<option>` tag with value in my `timesheet_jobs` field which is Foreign Key Field. Please help me to add one more extra `<option>` field in my `<select>` at the end after loading all the options.

forms.py

```
class ClockInForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = TimesheetEntry
            fields = ['timesheet_jobs', 'timesheet_clock_in_date', 'timesheet_clock_in_time']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    timesheet_jobs = self.fields['timesheet_jobs']                                    
    timesheet_jobs.choices = list(timesheet_jobs.choices)
    timesheet_jobs.choices.append(tuple(('create_new_job', 'Create New Job')))
```